# Tree Command not working in some directories

Tags: command-line, tree

I was learning about virtual environments and projects. While watching videos I encountered '`tree` command I installed `tree` and then run it. But it is not working on other partition of my HDD other than `/` partition.

When I use `tree` in  ***~/Documents***, I get desired results

```
$ tree -d    
.
├── Desktop
└── Fix ‘No WiFi Adapter Found’ for HP Laptops with Ubuntu 18.04 _ UbuntuHandbook_files

2 directories
```

But when I use it in other partition, I get

```
sandeep@sandeep-HP-Laptop-15q-ds0xxx:/media/sandeep/sandeep files$ tree -d
. [error opening dir]

0 directories
```

Comment: How did you install tree? Is it a snap package?

Comment: @Kulfy I installed it by sudo snap install tree

Comment: could it be an issue of reading rights? `tree -d` needs reading rights, so if you don't had then -> access denied

Answer (score 10):

I got the same error. Here's what I did to resolve it:

```
$ sudo snap remove tree
$ rm -rf $HOME/tree
$ sudo apt-get install tree
$ exec -l $SHELL  # <= restart shell
```

Over time, I've found that **snap** causes a lot of issues.

This is just one example.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "rm -rf $HOME/snap/tree" ?

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR**

1. If you want to continue using snap version of tree,

   - Either *connect removable media* to snap using

     ```
     snap connect tree:removable-media
     ```
   - Or change mount point of the device. See below for details
2. Alternatively use deb version of `tree` which can be installed using APT.

---

**Longer version:**

Whenever a partition/removable media is mounted, the target point is usually ***/media/USER/UUID***. But as per [limitations of Snap](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/limitations-in-snapd/9718), Snap applications can't guarantee the access of directories/files outside of current user's `$HOME` and that include directories such as ***/media*** and even ***/etc***. From [zyga's](https://forum.snapcraft.io/u/zyga) [post](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/limitations-in-snapd/9718):

> - The `$HOME` directory of the user must match `/home/*`. Other directories are not supported yet. In particular `/home/subdir/user` is also not supported.
> - any installation where the user’s home is not available if they're not logged in, is not yet supported. This includes:
>
>   - installations using `automount`
>   - ecryptfs and similar tech that unencrypt the $HOME directory (or partition) only while the user is logged in
>
> Note here “not supported” does not mean “doesn’t work”. Some things might not work, but also some sequences of events might result in a user not being able to access their data.

However, `tree` that is installed via APT can access those (DEBs don't have such limitations). So, if you need `tree` to work in other partitions, either install `tree` using APT. For that, run

```
sudo apt install tree
```

Or mount the partition in `$HOME`. For mounting a partition, you can use either `mount` command or edit `/etc/fstab`.

- If using, [`mount`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/mount.8.html),

  - Create a directory in any subdirectory of `$HOME`, for example, `test` in ***~/Desktop***

    ```
    mkdir ~/Desktop/test
    ```
  - `mount` works only with `sudo` privileges, therefore, run

    ```
    sudo mount /path/of/partition/ ~/Desktop/test
    ```

    (Replace `/path/of/partition/` with the partition/device path, for example, /dev/sda3)

This won't automatically mount partition in that folder. Thus if you mount and unmount partition again and again, the command needs to be re-run.

- If editing `/etc/fstab`:

  - Obtain UUID using

    ```
    blkid /path/of/partition
    ```

    (Replace `/path/of/partition/` with the partition/device path, for example, /dev/sda3)
  - Open `/etc/fstab` with `sudo` privileges using a text editor such as `nano` and add this line:

    ```
    UUID Mount_point Partition_type
    ```

    where UUID is obtained from the previous command, mount point is ***~/Desktop/test*** (lets say) and partition type is the type of partition such as ntfs or ext4.

This automatically mounts partition in the given mount point even after just a tap in Nautilus.

Once you're done you can use `tree` with `sudo` privileges, since both will mount the partition with `sudo` privileges and hence owner would be `root`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a novice learning about ubuntu and linux today.
My teacher showed me how to make directories using the:

mkdir -p mydir/mysubdir2/mysubdir3

and then using the tree command to get an overview that it was done. However, I didnt have the tree command installed, so I got it installed through "sudo apt install tree"
but got the same error as you when I tried "tree mydir" from the directory I created them.

I played around and saw that I forgot an "/" at the end, so if I wrote "tree mydir/" it worked like a charm.

Not sure if that helped, but I hope so! :)

Answer (score 0):

sandeep@sandeep-HP-Laptop-15q-ds0xxx:/media/sandeep/sandeep files$ tree -d
. [error opening dir]

0 directories

I got the same issue, and used "sudo tree" and it showed all the folders and files, may be some folders in it required root user access to open it. Please try it on.