# How to give a snap access to an sd card

Tags: snap

I was wondering how you give a snap access to an SD card or an external drive.
I've tried going into my package manager and changing the permissions through there but I couldn't find anything to give the program access to an external drive so I came here.
I'm using Kubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Which version of Linux and which release number is in use? Different releases have different tools. Please click [edit] and add that to your question; please do not use Add Comment as that's our one-way channel to you.

Comment: Related: [Tree Command not working in some directories](https://askubuntu.com/q/1178918/816190)

Comment: Depends if the snap specifies `removable-media` as an interface. Use `snap connections (snapname)` to find out if it does. If so, you can connect it with `snap connect (snapname):removable-media`

Comment: What do you do if it doesn't have that plug.

Answer (score 0):

I connected the Ultimaker Cura snap to the sd card like this:

```
$ snap connect cura-slicer:removable-media
```

Now, the Ultimaker Cura detects the sd card:

[image: Ultimaker Cura snap under Ubuntu detects sd card]

Thanks to [@popey](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240718/how-to-give-a-snap-access-to-an-sd-card#comment2090753_1240718).